# Compile time for loop throwing "parser stack overflow, program too complex"

Tags: c++, for-loop, parsing, stack-overflow, compile-time

The following is a compile-time for loop:

```
namespace nstl
{
template <typename index_type, index_type begin, index_type stride, index_type... indices, typename function_type>
void compile_time_for_internal(std::index_sequence<indices...>, function_type function)
{
  (function(begin + indices * stride), ...);
}
template <typename index_type, index_type begin, index_type end, index_type stride, typename function_type>
void compile_time_for(function_type function)
{
  compile_time_for_internal<index_type, begin, stride>(std::make_index_sequence<end-begin>{}, function);
}
}
```

When I attempt to run this loop with up to 596 elements it works:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  auto data = std::vector<double>(596);
  std::iota(data.begin(), data.end(), 0);

  auto sum(0.0);
  nstl::compile_time_for<std::size_t, 0, 596, 1>([&] (const auto& i)
  {
    sum += data[i];
  });
}
```

If I use 597 elements, it throws "parser stack overflow, program too complex". I already have ideas about why this might be happening, such as the fold expressions using some sort of recursion to expand the function call at compile-time, but this is just theory. So I'd like to ask: What are the reasons for this? Are there workarounds to avoid this issue?

Comment: which compiler are you using?

Comment: Different compilers have different limits for nested compile-time evaluation. Look at [this](https://godbolt.org/z/qd34q66zo). Your code compiles fine in GCC but fails in Clang which has a nesting limit of 256.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gcc compiles your code without issues also with 597: https://godbolt.org/z/15ETd9rKM. I tried to increase the depth, but I only saw godbolt killing the process before gcc itself reported an error.

Clang, reports the following [error message](https://godbolt.org/z/rMEcWe6vY):

```
<source>:11:40: fatal error: instantiating fold expression with 597 arguments exceeded expression nesting limit of 256
  (function(begin + indices * stride), ...);
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
<source>:16:3: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'nstl::compile_time_for_internal<unsigned long, 0UL, 1UL, 0UL, 1UL, 2UL, 3UL, 4UL, 5UL, 6UL, 7UL, 8UL, 9UL, 10UL, 11UL, 12UL, 13UL, 14UL, 15UL, 16UL, 17UL, 18UL, 19UL, 20UL, 21UL, 22UL, 23UL, 24UL, 25UL, 26UL, 27UL, 28UL, 29UL, 30UL, 31UL, 32UL, 33UL, 34UL, 35UL, 36UL, 37UL, 38UL, 39UL, 40UL, 41UL, 42UL, 43UL, 44UL, 45UL, 46UL, 47UL, 48UL, 49UL, 50UL, 51UL, 52UL, 53UL, 54UL, 55UL, 56UL, 57UL, 58UL, 59UL, 60UL, 61UL, 62UL, 63UL, 64UL, 65UL, 66UL, 67UL, 68UL, 69UL, 70UL, 71UL, 72UL, 73UL, 74UL, 75UL, 76UL, 77UL, 78UL, 79UL, 80UL, 81UL, 82UL, 83UL, 84UL, 85UL, 86UL, 87UL, 88UL, 89UL, 90UL, 91UL, 92UL, 93UL, 94UL, 95UL, 96UL, 97UL, 98UL, 99UL, 100UL, 101UL, 102UL, 103UL, 104UL, 105UL, 106UL, 107UL, 108UL, 109UL, 110UL, 111UL, 112UL, 113UL, 114UL, 115UL, 116UL, 117UL, 118UL, 119UL, 120UL, 121UL, 122UL, 123UL, 124UL, 125UL, 126UL, 127UL, 128UL, 129UL, 130UL, 131UL, 132UL, 133UL, 134UL, 135UL, 136UL, 137UL, 138UL, 139UL, 140UL, 141UL, 142UL, 143UL, 144UL, 145UL, 146UL, 147UL, 148UL, 149UL, 150UL, 151UL, 152UL, 153UL, 154UL, 155UL, 156UL, 157UL, 158UL, 159UL, 160UL, 161UL, 162UL, 163UL, 164UL, 165UL, 166UL, 167UL, 168UL, 169UL, 170UL, 171UL, 172UL, 173UL, 174UL, 175UL, 176UL, 177UL, 178UL, 179UL, 180UL, 181UL, 182UL, 183UL, 184UL, 185UL, 186UL, 187UL, 188UL, 189UL, 190UL, 191UL, 192UL, 193UL, 194UL, 195UL, 196UL, 197UL, 198UL, 199UL, 200UL, 201UL, 202UL, 203UL, 204UL, 205UL, 206UL, 207UL, 208UL, 209UL, 210UL, 211UL, 212UL, 213UL, 214UL, 215UL, 216UL, 217UL, 218UL, 219UL, 220UL, 221UL, 222UL, 223UL, 224UL, 225UL, 226UL, 227UL, 228UL, 229UL, 230UL, 231UL, 232UL, 233UL, 234UL, 235UL, 236UL, 237UL, 238UL, 239UL, 240UL, 241UL, 242UL, 243UL, 244UL, 245UL, 246UL, 247UL, 248UL, 249UL, 250UL, 251UL, 252UL, 253UL, 254UL, 255UL, 256UL, 257UL, 258UL, 259UL, 260UL, 261UL, 262UL, 263UL, 264UL, 265UL, 266UL, 267UL, 268UL, 269UL, 270UL, 271UL, 272UL, 273UL, 274UL, 275UL, 276UL, 277UL, 278UL, 279UL, 280UL, 281UL, 282UL, 283UL, 284UL, 285UL, 286UL, 287UL, 288UL, 289UL, 290UL, 291UL, 292UL, 293UL, 294UL, 295UL, 296UL, 297UL, 298UL, 299UL, 300UL, 301UL, 302UL, 303UL, 304UL, 305UL, 306UL, 307UL, 308UL, 309UL, 310UL, 311UL, 312UL, 313UL, 314UL, 315UL, 316UL, 317UL, 318UL, 319UL, 320UL, 321UL, 322UL, 323UL, 324UL, 325UL, 326UL, 327UL, 328UL, 329UL, 330UL, 331UL, 332UL, 333UL, 334UL, 335UL, 336UL, 337UL, 338UL, 339UL, 340UL, 341UL, 342UL, 343UL, 344UL, 345UL, 346UL, 347UL, 348UL, 349UL, 350UL, 351UL, 352UL, 353UL, 354UL, 355UL, 356UL, 357UL, 358UL, 359UL, 360UL, 361UL, 362UL, 363UL, 364UL, 365UL, 366UL, 367UL, 368UL, 369UL, 370UL, 371UL, 372UL, 373UL, 374UL, 375UL, 376UL, 377UL, 378UL, 379UL, 380UL, 381UL, 382UL, 383UL, 384UL, 385UL, 386UL, 387UL, 388UL, 389UL, 390UL, 391UL, 392UL, 393UL, 394UL, 395UL, 396UL, 397UL, 398UL, 399UL, 400UL, 401UL, 402UL, 403UL, 404UL, 405UL, 406UL, 407UL, 408UL, 409UL, 410UL, 411UL, 412UL, 413UL, 414UL, 415UL, 416UL, 417UL, 418UL, 419UL, 420UL, 421UL, 422UL, 423UL, 424UL, 425UL, 426UL, 427UL, 428UL, 429UL, 430UL, 431UL, 432UL, 433UL, 434UL, 435UL, 436UL, 437UL, 438UL, 439UL, 440UL, 441UL, 442UL, 443UL, 444UL, 445UL, 446UL, 447UL, 448UL, 449UL, 450UL, 451UL, 452UL, 453UL, 454UL, 455UL, 456UL, 457UL, 458UL, 459UL, 460UL, 461UL, 462UL, 463UL, 464UL, 465UL, 466UL, 467UL, 468UL, 469UL, 470UL, 471UL, 472UL, 473UL, 474UL, 475UL, 476UL, 477UL, 478UL, 479UL, 480UL, 481UL, 482UL, 483UL, 484UL, 485UL, 486UL, 487UL, 488UL, 489UL, 490UL, 491UL, 492UL, 493UL, 494UL, 495UL, 496UL, 497UL, 498UL, 499UL, 500UL, 501UL, 502UL, 503UL, 504UL, 505UL, 506UL, 507UL, 508UL, 509UL, 510UL, 511UL, 512UL, 513UL, 514UL, 515UL, 516UL, 517UL, 518UL, 519UL, 520UL, 521UL, 522UL, 523UL, 524UL, 525UL, 526UL, 527UL, 528UL, 529UL, 530UL, 531UL, 532UL, 533UL, 534UL, 535UL, 536UL, 537UL, 538UL, 539UL, 540UL, 541UL, 542UL, 543UL, 544UL, 545UL, 546UL, 547UL, 548UL, 549UL, 550UL, 551UL, 552UL, 553UL, 554UL, 555UL, 556UL, 557UL, 558UL, 559UL, 560UL, 561UL, 562UL, 563UL, 564UL, 565UL, 566UL, 567UL, 568UL, 569UL, 570UL, 571UL, 572UL, 573UL, 574UL, 575UL, 576UL, 577UL, 578UL, 579UL, 580UL, 581UL, 582UL, 583UL, 584UL, 585UL, 586UL, 587UL, 588UL, 589UL, 590UL, 591UL, 592UL, 593UL, 594UL, 595UL, 596UL, (lambda at <source>:27:50)>' requested here
  compile_time_for_internal<index_type, begin, stride>(std::make_index_sequence<end-begin>{}, function);
  ^
<source>:27:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'nstl::compile_time_for<unsigned long, 0UL, 597UL, 1UL, (lambda at <source>:27:50)>' requested here
  nstl::compile_time_for<std::size_t, 0, 597, 1>([&] (const auto& i)
        ^
<source>:11:40: note: use -fbracket-depth=N to increase maximum nesting level
  (function(begin + indices * stride), ...);
                                       ^
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

And indeed when you use `-fbracket-depth=600` also clang compiles the code: https://godbolt.org/z/59Y8ze6a8.

I did not try MSVC, but I suppose all major 3 have a flag that lets you change that limit.

**Update:** I am not very familiar with MSCV (its the only one that reports a message saying "program too complex" when I did try it, so I suppose it is the one you are using). I was looking for a flag to increase the limit, but I didn't find one. So my assumption that all major 3 have such a flag seems to be wrong. A workaround is needed.

You can manually unroll the loop to decrease the depth of the templates:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

namespace nstl
{
template <typename index_type, index_type begin, index_type stride, index_type... indices, typename function_type>
void compile_time_for_internal(std::index_sequence<indices...>, function_type function)
{
  (function(begin + indices*2*stride),...);
  (function(begin + (indices*2+1)*stride),...);
}
template <typename index_type, index_type begin, index_type end, index_type stride, typename function_type>
void compile_time_for(function_type function)
{
  compile_time_for_internal<index_type, begin, stride>(std::make_index_sequence<(end-begin)/2>{}, function);
}
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  auto data = std::vector<double>(600);
  std::iota(data.begin(), data.end(), 0);

  auto sum(0.0);
  nstl::compile_time_for<std::size_t, 0, 600, 1>([&] (const auto& i)
  {
    sum += data[i];
  });
  std::cout << sum << "\n";
  sum = 0.0;
  for (int i=0; i < 100; ++i) sum+= i;
  std::cout << sum;
  
}
```

This is only for even number of iterations. To allow also odd number of iterations you would need to distinguish the two cases and handle the last iteration seperately. Of course you can unroll more iterations to push the limit further.

[Live Demo with clang, this time only `-fbracket-depth=300` (note: 600 iterations)](https://godbolt.org/z/oMTed8sq9). Unfortunately I wasn't able to test it with MSVC, due to some Internal Compiler Explorer error. Though, note that clang needs `-fbracket-depth=600` for the not-unrolled version while it can handle the unrolled one with half the depth.

Comment: You could probably add a depth of 2 "recursion" to make the pack expand reduced by a sqrt, of your compiler dies on a 600 element comma fold expand.  That might boost your limit to a quarter million.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I think my unrolled version had the same issue as the original and I rolled back my edit. Problem is that I cannot test it with MSCV.

Comment: well, I fixed the mistake (it wasnt correctly unrolled before) and added the godbolt link for clang

Comment: I am proposing do sqrt(iterations) iterations of stride*sqrt(iterations) stride each of which iterates over sqrt(iterations) at an offset.

Comment: @Yakk oh I think I get it now. My initial code wasn't actually doing any unrolling due to a mistake, I fixed that now, but I still don't have msvc available so I'll leave further tweaking to the reader